# Java error: non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, arrays, static

I know this is a fairly common error for noobs like myself, but I can't seem to read anything that I can understand. For my homework we need to create an array of longs called NumberList. One of the methods we need to complete is called toString, which obviously turns the array into a string to print.

1. So in my main method I simply created a blank NumberList object and tried running the toString() method on it. The compiler says "non-static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context". WHY!?
2. Secondly, I created a test array of longs that I want to pass into my NumberList object. I called the array testExample and made some arbitrary values. But when I write

> new NumberList(testExample);

I get more errors. Why can I not do this?

Finally here's my code. Please ignore every method except for main, the constructors, and the toString.

Thank you so much

```
public class NumberList implements java.util.Collection {

//instance stuff
private long[] longArray;

public static void main ( String[] args ) {

    long[] testExample;
    testExample = new long[3];     
    testExample[0] = 1;
    testExample[1] = 2;
    testExample[2] = 3;

    new NumberList();
    //System.out.println(
    NumberList.toString();
    //);

}


/** Constructs an empty number list. */
public NumberList(){
    longArray = new long[0];     
    //System.out.println(longArray.length);
}


/** Constructs a number list from an array of Longs. */
public NumberList( Long[] l ){
    int size = l.length;
    longArray = new long[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        longArray[i] = l[i];
    }
}

 /** This returns a stringy version of this number list. */
public String toString () {
    //System.out.println(this.length());
    return "why doesnt this work :(";
}   

/** Increases by one the number of instances of the given element in this collection. */
public boolean add ( Object obj ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    //return true if the element CAN be added
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


/** Adds all of the elements of the given number list to this one. */
public boolean addAll ( java.util.Collection c  ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


/** Removes all of the elements from this collection. */
public void clear () {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


/** Returns true iff this number list contains at least one instance of the specified element. */
public boolean contains ( Object obj ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    //
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/** Returns true iff this number list contains at least one instance of each element 
    in the specified list. Multiple copies of some element in the argument do not
    require multiple copies in this number list. */
public boolean containsAll ( java.util.Collection c ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}




/** Compares the specified object with this collection for equality. */
public boolean equals ( Object obj ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}




/** Returns the hashcode value for this collection. */
public int hashCode () {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    //return integer that represents the set uniquely
    //return hashcode based on the numbers in the array
    //hashCode should be equal in equal cases
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/** Returns true if this collection contains no elements. */
public boolean isEmpty () {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/** Returns an iterator over the elements in this collection. Replicated elements should
    be "iterated over" just once. */
public java.util.Iterator iterator () {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/** Removes a single instance of the specified element from 
    this collection, if it is present. */
public boolean remove ( Object obj ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/** Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained 
    in the specified collection. */
public boolean removeAll ( java.util.Collection c ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}




/** Retains only the elements in this collection that are contained in the specified collection. 
     In other words, removes from this collection all of its elements that are not contained in the 
     specified collection. */
public boolean retainAll ( java.util.Collection c ) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


/** Returns the number of elements in this number list, including duplicates. */
public int sizeIncludingDuplicates () {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/** Returns a Long[] containing all of the elements in this collection, not including duplicates. */
public Long[] toArray () {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/** Not supported for this class. */
public Object[] toArray ( Object[] obj ) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}




/** Returns the number of elements in this number list, not including duplicates. */
public int size () {
    System.out.println(longArray.length);
    return 0 ;
}




/** Returns the number of instances of the given element in this number list. */
public int count ( Object obj ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/** This so-called "static factory" returns a new number list comprised of the numbers in the specified array.
    Note that the given array is long[], not Long[]. */
public static NumberList fromArray ( long[] l ) {
    /* REPLACE THE NEXT STATEMENT WITH YOUR CODE */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

}

Comment: `NumberList.toString();` - `toString` is not a static method, you need an instance of the class to call it, `new NumberList().toString()` for example

Comment: "WHY!?" How much do you understand about `static`? You need to call `toString()` on a *specific instance* of `NumberList`... otherwise it doesn't make any sense. I suggest you go back to your Java book/tutorial/whatever and find the section on `static` members and instance members.

Comment: Next, one issue per post, please - your constructor issue (which looks like it's a matter of `Long[]` not being compatible with `long[]`) is entirely separate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a static method, toString on NumberList can only be called on a instance of the object NumberList.

You must use it as

```
//create a instance of nList
NumberList nList = new NumberList();
//call the method on the newly created instance of NumberList
nList.toString();
```